# How to capture scenario result in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor?

Tags: protractor, migration, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am Migrating Protractor Cucumber framework to Cypress using cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
I need to capture Scenario run result -pass or fail value also the scenario name

Earlier with cucumber,the result were available in the after hooks and I was using scenario.result.status to store the result refer below code

```
After(async function (scenario){
  let name: string = scenario.pickle.name;
  result = scenario.result.status;
});
```

I found "window.testState.currentScenario" in the web,but where does window come from ? I am getting error Cannot find name window.
Reference https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/285
Not finding similar implementation with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, Is there any Solution to this?

Another solution given in the issue-285 was by @amitguptagwl was to add the code Cypress.env('currentScenario', scenario) to lib/createTestFromScenario.js in runTest() to get the current scenario detail
But how to access result after this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging on web, I found resolution for the problem statement,Sharing my code snippet here

```
afterEach(function() {
 const name = Cypress.currentTest.title
 cy.log(name)
 const sceanrioStatus=(Cypress as any).mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.state
 cy.log(sceanrioStatus)
});
```

Here Cypress.currentTest.title will fetch the scenario name
and (Cypress as any).mocha .. state will fetch the scenario pass or fail result at run time (So Need not have to fetch this from JSON Report)
This function will capture result after each scenario/test case run

Answer (score 0):

To get the result, you can check the following official documentation to export the result in a JSON file: https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md.

In the JSON, you will retrieve all the scenarios, the results, the screenshots, ...

EDIT:

Otherwise, you can get the result after each Feature (not scenario), with:

```
on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {
   console.log(results)
})
```

in your `cypress.config.{ts,js}`. Warning, the flag `experimentalInteractiveRunEvents` should be activated. See https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-spec-api

Comment: I am using this ,using this json report is generated, But my requirement is to capture the scenario result in the function (or hook ) and pass it to api call

Comment: In your CI ? Or in local? Because in your CI, you can use the JSON

Comment: • both CI and local 
• In local reading json file and then pulling the result would be one way (Long Process) but I belive this would not be proper method as json file contains a lot of data that is used to convert it into HTML Report 
• Another issue with reading json is , Json file is generated post all the scenarios are executed but I need to capture result after each scenario is executed

Comment: I have updated my answer. After each test, it seems complicated by you can still retrieve the details after each Feature.